# redirect url in htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, redirect

My old URL is like below:

> www.mywebsite.com/job-control/indexfull/533756/Unity3D-Game-Developer

For SEO friendly I was changed URL in route.php of CodeIgniter file. Present my URL is like this.

> www.mywebsite.com/job-search/jobs/533756/Unity3D-Game-Developer

My doubt is if any one will enter old URL I need to redirect to new URL.

If any one would enter this URL

> www.mywebsite.com/job-control/indexfull/533756/Unity3D-Game-Developer

I need redirect to

> www.mywebsite.com/job-search/jobs/533756/Unity3D-Game-Developer.

I have 1000 of old URLs. How to redirect to new URL?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^job-control/indexfull/(.*)$ job-search/jobs/$1 [L,QSA]` might help.

Comment: working , Thanks ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect the entire directory of /job-control/indexfull/* to /job-search/jobs/* use:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^job-control/indexfull/(.*)$ /job-control/indexfull/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If you are just trying to redirect the old link to the new link, use:

```
Redirect 301 /job-control/indexfull/533756/Unity3D-Game-Developer /job-search/jobs/533756/Unity3D-Game-Developer
```

Comment: Its Working for me , Thank you soooooooooo much @Matthew Sabatini